# Java return correct type of enum

Tags: java, enums

If I have the following

```
public enum MY_ENUM_THING
{
  NAME("JOE"),
  SOMETHING,
  ISWORKING(true);

  private String parameter;
  private boolean truth;

  MY_ENUM_THING()
  {

  }
  MY_ENUM_THING(String parameter)
  {
    this.parameter = parameter;
  }
  MY_ENUM_THING(boolean truth)
  {
    this.truth = truth
  }

  public ?? getEnumValue()
  {
     // this method (return) is what would be jamming me up
  } 
}
```

How do I get my return to return whatever the type of the enum is?

Example and desired results

```
System.out.print(MY_ENUM_THING.NAME.getEnumValue());
//JOE
System.out.print(MY_ENUM_THING.SOMETHING.getEnumValue());
//SOMETHING  <-- just return SOMETHING.name()
System.out.print(MY_ENUM_THING.ISWORKING.getEnumValue());
//true
```

Comment: My two cents on this is that it seems like you don't want an Enum to combine those 3.

Comment: @Keyser I know. I just want to know if this IS possible for this type of situation or how people have tackled this problem

Comment: when would you return truth? when it is true?

Comment: Then the tough one is `SOMETHING`. If you have the other two and the string is never empty you could just check `parameter`. Sry, I'm all out of ideas :)

Comment: What is the motivation behind trying to do this? It seems like you are using enums incorrectly.

Comment: @Code-Guru I'm just trying to learn limitations, whether or not I have bad design ideas and or if it can be done in light of learning

Comment: People have tackled this problem by not writing code that produces this problem.  This just doesn't make sense as an enum.

Comment: @DonRoby lol I'll take that answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find a better design. Java does not work well like this. The only common class to all return types is Object (boolean -> Boolean). Do you want to check the class of the return type every time you call this method before you cast it to the appropriate type.

Your design is also bad as enums are meant to represent a finite set of values each with the same type and properties. You are creating three totally different objects that represent three different things.

You need to look at your use case and come up with a better design. You could even post a separate question asking for advice.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write such a method, it has different return types for each case! (unless you returned `Object`, but that would be messy.) As a matter of fact, I smell a design problem - every enumeration value should have values for each of its attributes, it's problematic to have values for some attributes and not for others.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
public String getEnumValue()
{
    if(parameter != null){
        return parameter;
    }
    if(truth != null){
        return Boolean.toString(truth);
    }
    return name();     
}
```

You should also change your boolean to a capital-B 'Boolean'

But, as others are saying, this may be questionable design.

To answer the real question "how do I return the type that matches the given varible?"  You don't.  You can, however, make the return value an Object if you want to preserve the actual return type of the value:

```
public Object getEnumValue()
{
    if(parameter != null){
        return parameter;
    }
    if(truth != null){
        return truth;
    }
    return this;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is wrong with classes and interfaces?

```
interface Thing<E> {
    E getValue();
}

class Name implements Thing<String>{
    private String parameter;
    Name(String p){parameter = p;}
    String getValue(){return parameter;}
}

class Something implements Thing<Void>{
    Void getValue(){return null;}
}

class IsWorking implements Thing<Boolean>{
    private boolean truth;
    IsWorking(boolean t){truth = t;}
    Boolean getValue(){return truth;}
}
```